# JQuery .animate couldn't calculate the left value after it exceeds 10000

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I am trying to do some kind of slider. I am just using the basic concept. I have a mask, a container div and individual items in it. Like:

```
<div id="mask"> ----> position:relative
   <div id="container"> -----> position: absolute
      <div class="item"></div> ----> each floated left.
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
             .....
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Everything is working fine, until the left value exceeds 10000 (or so I couldn't calculate it). When I click on next button it goes to the beginning and comes back to next item. It shows the correct item although it rolls back instead of just slide one item.

```
goToNextItem: function() {
            showcaseItemWrapper.animate({left: leftPosition -= showcaseItemWidth },1000);
        }
```

leftPosition is set to 0 initially.

What could be the problem? Could you please help?

Thanks in advance.

#### HOW DID I APPLY DAVIDE'S SOLUTION ? ####
I've set container's margin-left to -9999px and it's left to 9999px, and it worked!**

Best Rgds,
Ugur Korfali

Comment: FYI! My container's width measures 18684px. First I thought, it is related with the maximum integer value, however 18684 is not exceeding it.

Comment: One more additional note. I know it is jQuery .animate related, because if I use .css instead, it is working perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it is a jQuery bug:

http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/7287

I am experiencing the same here. 
If your div width is < 20000 you can use a workaround; modify margin up to 10000 and the modify the position (left or top, depending on your div orientation). It's not very elegant, but it does the job.
Davide

Comment: Thanks Davide! Actually you are right. It is not a elegant way to solve it but it indeed works. Thanks again.